# What is the correct way to define routes on continuous subnets?

Tags: networking

I'm dividing a 192.168.0.0/24 network into four subnetworks:

- 192.168.0.0/26 (subnet A)
- 192.168.0.64/26 (subnet B)
- 192.168.0.128/26 (subnet C)
- 192.168.0.192/26 (subnet D)

The first host of each subnet is the gateway, e.g. 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.65, etc. However, this is not the default gateway, so I will have to define separate routes.
Now, can I set a single static route for every system that belongs to these subnets?
e.g. for subnet A:

`route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eno2`

Not sure how broadcasting is affected like this. So, do I need to declare static routes for all subnets separately?

`route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eno2` `route add -net 192.168.0.64 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eno2` `route add -net 192.168.0.128 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eno2` `route add -net 192.168.0.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eno2`

In the last case, not sure if the first entry is required since the system is already a member of subnet A.

Comment: what do you mean with "broadcasting"? what do you want broadcasting to do?

Comment: no, end systems should be configured with their own networks and masks (that creates entry to send trafic within the same subnet locally), then you add gateway for each one (your first snippet). how to route between subnets, is then gateway's problem, not hosts. the first entry in the second snippen is incorrect, traffic for the same subnet is not routed, it is sent using layer 2 to the device.

Comment: I know that a broadcast address is an IP address that is used to target all systems on a specific subnet network instead of single hosts. Each subnet has its own broadcast address. But does one subnet broadcasts to other subnets? If so, if I use 192.168.0.0/24 as route, I guess it will only broadcast on 192.168.0.255 which is the same address for 192.168.0.192/26. Does it matter?

Comment: the simple answer is no. broadcast address for the network is so called "link local" broadcast, that is it only broadcasts to the systems in the same layer 2 segment (that is one subnet). and you should not be able to use a broadcast address of another network. i don't think getting a broadcast in separate lans will be that simple. you have to configure your gateways to do IP multicast. If your subnets are actually capable of reaching each other with layer 2 alone, you might be able to trick them into broadcasting, but i don't know how.

Comment: are you sure you need broadcast between the lans?

Comment: As far as I know, I do not use any protocol that broadcasts on another subnet.

Comment: i think the first entry will be enough. P.S. link-local broadcast is usually necessary for ARP (maybe other link-local stuff),  which is necessary so that the systems in the same subnet can communicate with each other **using layer 2**. you route between subnets, so they communicate via layer 3.  so, setting up something that enables them to communicate via layer 2 is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You need the last 3, not the first (assuming your host is on 192.168.0.0/26, for example 192.168.0.2).  There are 4 broadcast addrs; one for each subnet: 192.168.0.63, 192.168.0.127, 192.168.0.191, and 192.168.0.255 -- no configuration is needed for this.  With very rare exceptions, routers do not forward broadcasts, BTW.

Comment: I've already mentioned that the first route could be excessive as it describes a subnet that is considered as local. The reason that I've made this question is to check if 1 route rule with the whole network (/24) vs 3 route rules for each other subnet (/26), does make any difference. So far, I understand that broadcasting is being used locally, except from rare cases. I believe that if one endpoint needs to broadcast something on another subnet, the address belongs to the /24 network and the gateway is aware of the destination. So, isn't one route rule with the whole network correct?

Comment: I need to see the topology to go further.  You did not "already mentioned[sic]" that, rather you "not sure".   What is the "one route rule"; do you have a reference?